# Child div height based on it's parent

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a page which fills the height of the browser window (there should be no scrolling). On the page there are 2 divs (class=module), that should both be 50% of their parent (id=main).

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        This is the header.<br /><br />It's height could vary..
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <div class="module">
            module 1..
        </div>
        <div class="module">
            module 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that there is also a header div which can have a flexible height, so by specifying height:100% on #main results in the entire page scrolling (#main is given the height of the entire page rather than the height of the page minus the height of the header).

This of course results in each of the .module divs having a height of 50% of the entire page, rather than 50% of #main.

http://jsfiddle.net/pStDj/3/

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: Urm, each one is 50% of main...

Comment: You could provide a height restriction (if that's what you want) on the container.

Comment: Yes, but notice that the page can be scrolled? #main has a height equivalent to the height of the entire page - I need to make it take #header into account